# Open Modified Report from Action Button

Tags: acumatica

I modified Invoice/Memo (AR641000) report and kept the parameters as it was, but when pressing the action button (Reports-> Print Invoice/Memo) from Invoices and Memos screen, it generates the following error:

> Report does not contain parameters: ARInvoice.DocType0,
>   ARInvoice.RefNbr0

Could you please help me in figuring out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear, what did you do?

AR301000 - it's a screen and not a report. What kind of changes did you do and where, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry the report ID = AR641000. I have created my own version where the new report takes the same parameters (DocType, RefNbr)